# How can I randomize a Nextgen Gallery Slideshow

Tags: php, plugin-nextgen-gallery

Been googling for an hour now can't find the answer to what feels like a simple question.

I have a very basic slideshow.  I am using the shortcode to load it into the template page.

[nggallery id=1]

I have also customized the view file gallery.php.  Pretty much I just pulled out all the extra stuff and just have the foreach loop.

I have tried using the [php shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) on the $images array but that doesn't fix the problem.

```
shuffle($images);
foreach ( $images as $image ) :
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: have you tried - `[nggallery id=1 orderby="RAND"]`

Comment: I hadn't but I did and it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function defined in `nggfunctions.php` that you can use directly in the template page:

```
/* nggShowRandomRecent($type, $maxImages, $template, $galleryId) - return recent or random images
 * 
 * @access public
 * @param string $type 'id' (for latest addition to DB), 'date' (for image with the latest date), 'sort' (for image sorted by user order) or 'random'
 * @param integer $maxImages of images
 * @param string $template (optional) name for a template file, look for gallery-$template
 * @param int $galleryId Limit to a specific gallery
 * @return the content
*/
```

Or you can use this shortcode, defined in the `shortcodes.php` file:

```
 /**
 * Function to show a gallery of random or the most recent images with shortcode of type:
 * 
 * [random max="7" template="filename" id="2" /]
 * [recent max="7" template="filename" id="3" mode="date" /]
 * where 
 * - max is the maximum number of random or recent images to show
 * - template is a name for a gallery template, which is located in themefolder/nggallery or plugins/nextgen-gallery/view
 * - id is the gallery id, if the recent/random pictures shall be taken from a specific gallery only
 * - mode is either "id" (which takes the latest additions to the databse, default) 
 *               or "date" (which takes the latest pictures by EXIF date) 
 *               or "sort" (which takes the pictures by user sort order)
 * 
 * @param array $atts
 * @return the_content
 */
```

Comment: This looks like its what I am looking for.  should I simply use that function in my template file?  then provide values for those variables?

Comment: Yes, it should work like that. If not, you can also use the shortcode in the template file using the `do_shortcode` function like this: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[random max="7" template="filename" id="1" /]'); ?>`

Comment: That works great.  Thanks.  Doing this broke the use of jquery cycle through the plugin.  IS there something I need to do to put it back?  I can ask the question in a new Question if need be

Comment: You mean the slideshow doesn't work anymore?